# GetUsersInRole DataSource for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Hi I need to display in DropDownList a list of "Users" belonging a specific ROLE.

This is my code:

```
        // Find DropDownList
        DropDownList myUserList = (DropDownList)uxInsertAuthorInput.FindControl("uxUserListSelector");
        // Bind data to DropDownList
        myUserList.DataSource = Roles.GetUsersInRole("CMS-AUTHOR");
        myUserList.DataBind();
        myUserList.DataTextField = "UserName";
```

My problem is when a visitor select an item in DropDownList.
The actual value passed is the "UserName" and not the "UserId".

I need to use the "UserId" value when a visitor select an item from DropDownList.

How to do it?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the selected username and call [Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx).  You can then get the user ID using the [MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx) property.

Of course, if the goal was to get the MembershipUser from the user id, then you'll have the user after calling `GetUser`.

Comment: This is the right answer, although I'd use `Membership.GetUser(username)y` instead of Membership.FindUsersByName and just find the Id for the selected item.

Comment: I agree with the use of Membership.GetUser(username)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your .aspx code (or the designed if you used WYSIWYG).  Change the query in the SQL Datasource.  I did this similarly by using:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlUsersInRole0" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="GetUsersInRole" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="MaintenanceWorkers" Name="rolename" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I assume this can also be done programatically, but why bother?